# Why does a final collection still get updated?

Tags: java, collections, final

I've this code where I store two collections and then add an event listener (no lambda here - I need to stick to Java 7 ;) ).

```
    // rri is a ReturnRequestInterface 
    final Collection<BigDecimal> selectedItems = rri.getSelected();
    final Collection<BigDecimal> unselectedItems = rri.getUnSelected();

    rri.addInformationChangeEventListener(new ComponentInformationChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void informationChange(RequestChangeEvent event) {

            ReturnRequestInterface source = (ReturnRequestInterface) event.getSource();
            boolean debug1 = source.getSelected().containsAll(selectedItems);
            boolean debug2 = source.getUnSelected().containsAll(unselectedItems);

        }

    });
```

I've debugged this initially and the collection was correctly setup. It contained no objects, since the code was just initialized.

Debugging the listener (the event was fired because an item selection was made) left me confused. The booleans `debug1` and `debug2` are both true because the collection `selectedItems` and `unselectedItems` were updated according to the item selection. So, the event source collection contained the same items as the declared final collections (`selectedItems`, `unselectedItems`).

Don't the two declared final collections have to stay as they are?

Comment: `final` says that the *variable* cannot be changed, not that the object it refers to cannot be changed.

Comment: Because the variable `selectedItems` is `final`, though you can´t reassign it. But that doesn´t make your `Collection` `final`.

Comment: Also, are you sure that they were updated? Any set contains an empty set, so those booleans will be `true` if those sets are empty.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Yep, _really_ debugged it. ;P

Comment: @RealSkeptic Would you mind creating an answer with further explanation? I don't really get why this collections get updated. I feel like (regardless of the final modifier) they should stay as they are...

Comment: Not sure what "really debugged" means. Did you display the content of the collections in the debugger and find that they contain values? Also, it could be that `source.getSelected()` returns the same collection that was returned by `rri.getSelected()` originally, thus the old reference will point to the new content. It's hard to say without knowing what the classes of the objects are and how the `getSelected()` method is implemented.

Comment: @RealSkeptic "and find that they contain values?" That's what I've meant with _really_. However, I've done it like that: selectedItems = new ArrayList<BigDecimal>(); selectedItems.addAll(rri.getSelected());

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`final` simply means that a variable that has been declared `final` cannot be changed, and a class which is `final` cannot be inherited from.
all variables that aren't primitive are references in Java, which means that they 'point' or refer to an instance of an object, but are not objects themselves.

What you are referring to is called an immutable object, which is an instance of a `final class` that all of its fields are `final` and `private` and has no setters.

hope this helps clarify.

Comment: And from a practical point of view, if you want immutable `Collection`, use [java.util.Collections.unmodifiableCollection(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableCollection-java.util.Collection-) method to wrap the `rri.getSelected()` and `rri.getUnSelected()` collections.

Answer (score 2):

Using `final` only means that the reference cannot be changed to point at another object not whether its contents can be updated or not.

If you want an unmodifiable set use something like `Collections.unmodifiableSet(yourSet);`